How can I sort CSV files by columns like we see in the spreadsheets?
Suppose I have the following CSV file:
Column1,Column2,Column3
C,3,1
B,2,2
A,3,3
C,3,10
B,2,20
A,2,30
C,3,100
B,1,200
A,1,300

I want to sort it

First by Column1
Second by Column2
Third by Column3

So the outcome should be the following:
Column1,Column2,Column3
A,1,300
A,2,30
A,3,3
B,1,200
B,2,2
B,2,20
C,3,1
C,3,10
C,3,100

For sorting CSV by columns in ascending/descending order, I created the following class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace SikorskiLibMemoryLess
{
    public enum SortTypeEnum
    {
        Ascending,
        Descending
    }

    public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static string ToCommaSeparatedString(this List<string> list)
        {
            if (list == null || !list.Any())
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return string.Join(",", list);
        }
    }

    public class CSVSorter
    {
        public List<string> Header { get; private set; }
        public List<List<string>> Data { get; private set; }

        public CSVSorter()
        {
            Data = new List<List<string>>();
        }

        public void LoadCSV(string filePath, bool hasHeader = true)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string line;
                bool isFirstLine = true;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    List<string> columns = line.Split(',').Select(col => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(col) ? null : col).ToList();

                    if (isFirstLine && hasHeader)
                    {
                        Header = columns;
                        isFirstLine = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Data.Add(columns);
                        if (isFirstLine)
                        {
                            isFirstLine = false;
                            if (!hasHeader)
                            {
                                Header = Enumerable.Range(1, columns.Count).Select(i => "Column" + i).ToList();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void LoadCSV(string fileName, string fileDir, bool hasHeader = true)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(fileDir, fileName);
            LoadCSV(filePath, hasHeader);
        }

        public void LoadCSV(IEnumerable<List<string>> csvData, bool hasHeader = true)
        {
            bool isFirstLine = true;

            foreach (var columns in csvData)
            {
                var processedColumns = columns.Select(col => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(col) ? null : col).ToList();
                if (isFirstLine && hasHeader)
                {
                    Header = processedColumns;
                    isFirstLine = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Data.Add(processedColumns);
                    if (isFirstLine)
                    {
                        isFirstLine = false;
                        if (!hasHeader)
                        {
                            Header = Enumerable.Range(1, processedColumns.Count).Select(i => "Column" + i).ToList();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Sort(int[] columns, SortTypeEnum ascendingOrDescending)
        {
            try
            {
                IOrderedEnumerable<List<string>> sortedData = null;

                if (ascendingOrDescending == SortTypeEnum.Ascending)
                {
                    sortedData = Data.OrderBy(row => GetColumnValueSafe(row, columns[0]));
                    for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++)
                    {
                        sortedData = sortedData.ThenBy(row => GetColumnValueSafe(row, columns[i]));
                    }
                }

                Data = sortedData.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error during sorting: {ex.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private string GetColumnValueSafe(List<string> row, int columnIndex)
        {
            return columnIndex < row.Count ? row[columnIndex] : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<List<string>> Get()
        {
            yield return Header;
            foreach (var row in Data)
            {
                yield return row;
            }
        }

        public void SaveCSV(string filePath)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                // Write the header
                sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", Header));

                // Write the data rows
                foreach (var row in Data)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row.Select(col => col ?? "")));
                }
            }
        }

        public void SaveCSV(string fileName, string fileDir)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(fileDir, fileName);
            SaveCSV(filePath);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Example usage for CSV with potential missing data
            CSVSorter sorter = new CSVSorter();
            sorter.LoadCSV(@"C:\git\rouse_data~~\[PENULTIMATE]\OUTPUT_CSV\input.csv", true); // Adjust path as needed
            sorter.Sort(new int[] { 0,1,2 }, SortTypeEnum.Ascending); // Sort by the second column (e.g., particleVolume) in ascending order
            sorter.SaveCSV(@"C:\git\rouse_data~~\[PENULTIMATE]\OUTPUT_CSV\sorted___input.csv");

            // Display sorted data
            foreach (var row in sorter.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", row));
            }
        }
    }
}

This class is not giving me the desired result.
Column1,Column2,Column3
C,3,1
B,2,2
A,3,3
C,3,10
B,2,20
A,2,30
C,3,100
B,1,200
A,1,300

Is there any open source library for sorting CSV data by columns?

The way i'd do it is to sort the initial column (in this case Column 1), then get the corresponding values for the second and third columns that belong to each sorted group from Column 1 and sort them.

In your sample code you just sort by the first column but your requirement is to sort by the first, then second, then third. So why you didn't pass new int[] { 0, 1, 2 } and post us the result?

In your sample code you don't use the desired parameter new int[]{0, 1, 2}(edit: now you fixed it in your question), since you want to sort by the first column and then by the others. If you do so you will get an IndexOutOfRangeException(in your catch). The reason for this is a subtle bug in your loop:
for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++)
{
    sortedData = sortedData.ThenBy(row => GetColumnValueSafe(row, columns[i]));
}

Resharper would tell you here: "captured variable is modified in the outer scope" and that is causing it. So the fix is easy, create a copy of that variable;
for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++)
{
    int colIndex = i;
    sortedData = sortedData.ThenBy(row => GetColumnValueSafe(row, columns[colIndex]));
}

another - better - option is to use a foreach(C#5 fixed it):
foreach (int column in columns)
{
    sortedData = sortedData.ThenBy(row => GetColumnValueSafe(row, column));
}

See this answer for more details: Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?
Now you get the desired result, since everything else seems to work properly:
Column1,Column2,Column3
A,1,300
A,2,30
A,3,3
B,1,200
B,2,2
B,2,20
C,3,1
C,3,10
C,3,100

